# Android Studio 4.X removed export to zip file?

Tags: android, export, android-studio-4.1

There used to be `export to zip file` option in Android Studio (AS).

For AS4.X, I could not find it. Anyone know how to export an Android Project to zip file.

[image: no export to zip option]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 4.2.1 it is moved to **File->Export-> Export to Zip file**

[image]

Comment: It is really confusing to put it in `Manage IDE settings`

Answer (score 1):

no.. in 4.1, its now has been moved to **File - > Manage IDE Settings - > Export to Zip file**